# How do I back up Windows to a smaller hard drive using Linux software?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, restore

I have a 320GB hard drive that has about 50GB used, with a borked Windows install (I think). I need to grab a 1-1 copy of it before I send it to the manufacturer for fixing, since the latest backup is from 3 days ago, and some important changes have happened since then. The original hard drive has 23 bad sectors, which is why I'm trying to grab the data now.

I have a 80GB external drive that will hold all the data - how do I copy the data? I have a Ubuntu liveUSB that I'm using, so whatever solution that I use to do it needs to be using Linux tools.

Answer (score 1):

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) should be able to do this.

Comment: Additionally, if your destination partition is smaller than your source partition, then you'll need to check the "-icds" option in "Expert mode" to ignore the partition size check.